# How to deploy my Dynamic web project on internet

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, publish

I am working in my final year project and I created a web service in a dynamic web project using eclipse JEE, tomcat 8.5 and Axis 2 ( all this is running in Ubuntu 16). this web servicie calls some programs that are installed on a computer ( Matlab for instance) so I need this computer to host the Web Service. This web service works fine in local host ( I created a client  to check it) now I need to do the next step. how can I deploy this web service on internet? ( NO localhost), There is any tutorial or documentation to do something like this? The computer where I am working is of my university so it is connected to the university network.

I have read that I need a WAR file, I know that if  I right click my project and the select export it says "WAR file", this  war is going to have all the references and .jar that I added ? ( I am afraid of this because I neeeded to add some .jar and also some native library locations to them) Also I know that I need to have a Statc IP instead of a dynamic one. how can I achieve it if I have no access to the university routers?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need a host/server that has tomcat up and running too

Comment: What do you mean ?
The computer should be  the server host?
it  has required programs installed.

Comment: I suppose you need to buy a web server from a web hosting provider like `GoDaddy` ? or you can sign up with (https://www.heroku.com) `heroku`and get a free java clod platform to test your application.

Comment: unless you plan to expose your working computer to the internet, which I wouldn't do, you need a server where to deploy your war and with matlab

Comment: If it's just for a school project (aka you don't plan on leaving it up forever) you can just open the required ports and run the server from your development computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your own domain, then you will have to buy a domain if you want to be on internet. There are website like [GoDaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/offers/domains?isc=goflin147&currencytype=INR&cvosrc=ppc.google.godaddy&cvo_crid=177126523832&matchtype=p&mkwid=sgqgSfORF_pcrid_177126523832_pkw_godaddy_pmt_p_pdv_c&gclid=CMHxn8T5h9MCFdaJaAodXRoDKQ) or [BigRock](https://www.bigrock.in/deals-on-domains-v13?a_aid=4d2c643cb0d0a&location=IN&chan=ga_se_brgennew&ad=ga_se_brgennew&cmp=Bigrock_Generic(S)_com_99_%20_2yrs&kw=Big%20rock&mt=e&adg=Bigrock_Exact&adid=181119497165&coupon=BRCOM99SEM2YR&gclid=CMmTvsj5h9MCFdgTaAodOoID1w), that provide domains.

If you are doing it for testing or demonstration purpose, you can use [NGROK](https://ngrok.com/) tool. This tool will provide a domain over internet (something like http://.ngrok.io), that will be mapped to your localhost. The domain can be customized if you are using paid version.

```
ngrok.exe http 8080
```

**OR**

```
ngrok.exe start -config="config.yml" config-name
```

config.yml

```
http_proxy: ""
log: ngrok.log
tunnels:
  config-name:
    proto: http
    addr: 8080
```

Comment: Hi, Have you ever use this?
If I have 2 different projects ( Dynamic Web projects ) each for a different app if  I configurate the Domain given by NGROK tool to my local host  and I select in one of the projects the option ¨Run on server¨ (local host in this case)   the url will  ¨Host¨ that project ? and then if I decide to ¨Run on server¨ the other project the URL will host the new project instead?
As easy as that ?

Comment: yes..it is simple..it is doing nothing but mapping an internet web address to your localhost and port you specify. I have used it at both personal and professional level. It works good.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you need a "computer to host the Web Service" on internet, as you also have the constrain to use specific libraries so you cannot use a "ready-to-host"(paas) solution like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) because you wouldn't have access/control to the computer hosting your webapp. The only solution I know to deal with that is VPS hosting (https://www.ovh.com/us/vps/) with that you can "rent" a remote computer (with ubuntu 16 if you want) and have total control on it for example you can install whatever native library you want on it, and also any servlet container/web server you want like you would on your local computer.

But then your web service will be on internet, which is "outside" the university network, if you need to access some data/services only accessible from the university network, you cannot use this solution unless you have a special (and secured) access to connect the university network via [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) for example but you'd have to ask to your university if something exists in the university network to allow traffic coming from internet (which I suppose is not the case...but you can still ask to the IT department of the university). Anyway, what you want to do cannot be achieved the "easy-way", lot of work foreseen to have something like this working. If it's a university project, maybe it should stay inside the university network.

Comment: It does not matter if the Web service is used for someone outside the university, so the VPS hosting is the answer right? Are they going to install the requiered software? Matlab for instance?

Comment: unfortunately no, you'd have to install everything you need by yourself with this solution, as you probably did on your local computer to have it working. With this VPS solution you only have an empty system (you can choose Ubuntu/fedora/windows...) but the remaining configuration relies on your needs...

Comment: Okay , I understand what you are saying, but I  would like to say that I need the web service visible for everyone not just University people,  AND for us   the computer  does not  matter , I mean   we dont care about the information on it if it gets damaged it does not matter.
So there is a way to publish the server in that computer ?
I think need tomething that connnectsthe web service url with the computr or something like that

Comment: what do you thing of Ambers answer

Comment: yes "there is a way to publish the server in that computer", and it's to install the server on the VPS once you have access to it, for that you will recieve an email from the vps hosting company with the ip address of the VPS and an SSH access to it (a standard protocol to connect on remote linux systems via a command line tool like bash). At this point you can choose to install the server you need via the command line/SSH, or you can eventually choose to install a desktop environment on the remote machine and to access to it via x2Go server for example (that you'll have to install yourself)